# Android AnimatedExpandableListView getGroupView groupposition always shows 0

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

`AnimatedExpandableListView  getGroupView` shows always 0th position and its `getCount` shows `6`. and it displays always 0th position value and it is not showing any children. Any one suggest me what is the problem in below adapter source code

**Here is my code:**

```
private class MenuAdapter extends AnimatedExpandableListView.AnimatedExpandableListAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<CategoryObj>>> subCatArrayList;
        Context ct;
        public MenuAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            ct=context;
        }

        public void setData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<CategoryObj>>> catList) {
            this.subCatArrayList = catList;
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, ArrayList<CategoryObj>> getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return subCatArrayList.get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getRealChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ChildHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ChildHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_sublist, parent, false);
                holder.mMenu_SubCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subcat_item);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            if(groupPosition == 0){
                holder.mMenu_SubCategory.setText(subCatArrayList.get(groupPosition).get("A").get(childPosition).getSubCat_name());
            }else if(groupPosition == 1){
                holder.mMenu_SubCategory.setText(subCatArrayList.get(groupPosition).get("B").get(childPosition).getSubCat_name());
            }else if(groupPosition == 2){
                holder.mMenu_SubCategory.setText(subCatArrayList.get(groupPosition).get("C").get(childPosition).getSubCat_name());
            }else if(groupPosition == 3){
                holder.mMenu_SubCategory.setText(subCatArrayList.get(groupPosition).get("D").get(childPosition).getSubCat_name());
            }else if(groupPosition == 4){
                holder.mMenu_SubCategory.setText(subCatArrayList.get(groupPosition).get("E").get(childPosition).getSubCat_name());
            }else if(groupPosition == 5){
                holder.mMenu_SubCategory.setText(subCatArrayList.get(groupPosition).get("F").get(childPosition).getSubCat_name());
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRealChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, ArrayList<CategoryObj>> getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return subCatArrayList.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            Log.v("srinu", "group count:"+Globals.CatList().size());
            return Globals.CatList().size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            GroupHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new GroupHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_categories, parent, false);
                holder.mMenu_Category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cat_item);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.mMenu_Category.setText(Globals.CatList().get(groupPosition));

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return true;
        }


    }
    private static class ChildHolder {
        TextView mMenu_SubCategory;
    }

    private static class GroupHolder {
        TextView mMenu_Category;
    }
```

Comment: @cyberlobe i don't have above 10 reputation for add image. it showing string "hi".. like TextView..  array is like this:["hi","bye","see"]. and i mean it shows 0th position value.. i printed log for getView group position, it always print position 0

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739690/getgroupview-in-the-second-level-expandablelistview-always-has-the-same-grou